# ¿Cómo puedo leer o crear ficheros .txt con Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode

Anteriormente he trabajado con Code::Blocks. Para leer un fichero solamente era necesario ubicarlo en la carpeta del proyecto y el programa lo leía, y a la hora de crear un fichero este aparecía en la carpeta del proyecto.

Xcode no funciona así. ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacerlo?

Gracias.

[image: He introducido el archivo en la carpeta]
[image: No lo reconoce]

Comment: ¿Te refieres para que el programa reconozca el fichero?

Comment: Exáctamente lo mismo: pon el archivo en la carpeta donde el ejecutable se genera y ábrelo con [fstream](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open).

Comment: Es el problema, que no funciona :/ He adjuntado imágenes

Comment: `ejemplo.txt` debe estar en el directorio de **ejecución** de tu código, el que aparezca o no en el proyecto (sea cual sea el IDE) es indiferente. ¿En qué carpeta se genera tu archivo `.exe`?

Comment: @sel8 no puedes hacer preguntas de como usar tu ide en la sección de C++ te recomiendo que visites el centro de ayuda.- saludos. http://es.stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 1):

Prueba utilizando `fopen`, es muy sencillo de usar, en tu caso sería algo como:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
   FILE *fp;
   int c;

   fp = fopen("ejemplo.txt","r");
   while(1){
      c = fgetc(fp);
      if(feof(fp)){
         break;
      }
      printf("%c", c);
   }
   fclose(fp);
   return(0);
}
```

Si no te funciona esto, revisa los permisos de lectura del archivo *ejemplo.txt*

Comment: `fopen` pertenece a la librería de C, mientras que la pregunta es de C++. Además es más complicado de usar y más inseguro que los streams de archivo como `fstream`. Además, tu respuesta no responde la pregunta.

Comment: Tienes razón en cuanto a que pertenece a una librería de C, aun así la respuesta satisface la pregunta "leer o crear ficheros .txt con Xcode". Igual muchas gracias por tu observación.

Comment: El problema de [sel8](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/38002/2742) no es que no sepa abrir archivos. Ya ha demostrado saber cómo hacerlo pues ha mostrado un código perfectamente válido con `ifstream`; su problema es que el ejecutable no localiza el archivo a abrir. Así pues, darle una alternativa a `ifstream` **no responde la pregunta**.

Answer (score 1):

Yo, creo, tengo la solución: tienes que poner la extensión entera!
mira:
éste es un programa que lee en el archivo "pa.txt" números y los muestra en pantalla
como verás al abrir el archivo (fich.open()) en las comillas pongo el users/miusuario/documents/carpetas... hasta llegar al archivo
por xcode sale en algún sitio "full path" donde podrás encontrar dónde se localiza el archivo main.cpp y allí pones tu texto .txt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    int num;
    if stream fich;

    fich.open("/Users/yomismo/Documents/CodeBlocks/guion9/conxcode/guion9/guion9/pa.txt");
    if (fich.is_open() == true)
    {
        while (fich.eof() == false)
        {
            fich >> num;
            cout << num << endl;
        }
        fich.close();
     }
     else cout << "Error al abrir archivo." << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te decían arriba, necesitas colocar el text file en el mismo directorio donde corre tu ejecutable. Para obtener la ubicación de tu ejecutable, abre el menú contextual del producto y selecciona *Show in Finder*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahí colocas tus text files:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]